# Accessing a pgfkeys value

Tags: pgfkeys

Perhaps I am fundamentally misunderstanding what `\pgfkeys` does, but I would like to use it as a way to store and retrieve data in my tex document. Based on the documentation, I would expext

```
\pgfkeys{/a/b=my value}
Hi there \pgfkeys{/a/b}!
```

to insert `Hi there my value!` into the document. The only way I have managed to get something similar to work is with

```
\pgfkes{/a/b/.code=#1, /a/b/.default=my value}
Hi there \pgfkeys{/a/b}!
```

but this definitely seems like improper usage to me...

How can I just set values and retrieve them later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is essentially correct but you need to set up the key properly first. Once the keys have been defined properly you can use `\pgfkeys{/a/b}` and `\pgfkeysvalueof{/a/b}` to access the current value.

For example, the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{/a/.is family, /a,
  b/.initial=my value
}

\begin{document}

  Hi there ``\pgfkeys{/a/b}''!

  \pgfkeys{/a/b=a new value}
  You can also use ``\pgfkeysvalueof{/a/b}''.

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]